# Send e-mail with PHP to Facebook group mail address

Tags: php, facebook, email, social-networking, sendmail

**1,** I tried to send *e-mail* in *PHP* to my *Facebook* group email, but these updates, doesn't appear. If I send the *e-mail* from my *yahoo mail*, it posted instantly. What kind of information should I add to the mail header?

**2,** Is is possible to add images as *attachments*?

My current *mail sender* code is:

```
<?php
    $to = "mygroup@groups.facebook.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "me@yahoo.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: If you are trying to send from PHP and using the `From:` address as a Yahoo! account, I'd guess you are running into [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) related problems, amongst other things. In order to get around this, you will need to relay your mail via Yahoo! and authenticate against your account, and in order to facilitate this you should use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). `Is is possible to add images as attachments?` - Yes. Again, the two libraries above will help with this.

Comment: @DaveRandom - you should have made that an answer!

Comment: @dawmail333 I know I realised that after I submitted it, but you wrote basically the same thing at the same time as me, so I just +1ed yours. It would be worth you adding the SwiftMailer/PHPMailer links to your answer, they will make the OPs task much easier ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the email need to come from "me@yahoo.com"? Because Yahoo mail uses [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), which Facebook can use to verify that your email didn't actually come from there, and discard your email as a spoofing attempt.

If the email needs to come from me@yahoo.com, [you'll need to connect to Yahoo mail through SMTP](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/36108-send-emails-using-php-smtp-direct/), and pass your username and password through, and legitimately send your email from there.

As for image attachments, [it's possible](http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/mail2.htm).

EDIT: As per the lovely DaveRandom's comment, the following PHP packages should make your job MUCH easier: [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)